# Elastic Beanstalk Ruby failing on private subnet

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-vpc

I have a ruby application deployed to Elastic Beanstalk that successfully deploys and runs when connected to my public subnet but fails with an error when connected to my private subnet.

```
2023/01/04 21:16:25.937590 [INFO] Running command /bin/su webapp -c bundle exec /opt/elasticbeanstalk/config/private/checkforraketask.rb assets:precompile
2023/01/04 21:16:26.178594 [INFO] bundler: failed to load command: /opt/elasticbeanstalk/config/private/checkforraketask.rb (/opt/elasticbeanstalk/config/private/checkforraketask.rb)
/opt/elasticbeanstalk/config/private/checkforraketask.rb:16:in `require': cannot load such file -- rake (LoadError)
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/config/private/checkforraketask.rb:16:in `<top (required)>'
    from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.7.7/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.7.0/bundler/cli/exec.rb:58:in `load'
    from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.7.7/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.7.0/bundler/cli/exec.rb:58:in `kernel_load'
    from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.7.7/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.7.0/bundler/cli/exec.rb:23:in `run'
    from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.7.7/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.7.0/bundler/cli.rb:491:in `exec'
    from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.7.7/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.7.0/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
    from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.7.7/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.7.0/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command'
    from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.7.7/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.7.0/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor.rb:392:in `dispatch'
    from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.7.7/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.7.0/bundler/cli.rb:34:in `dispatch'
    from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.7.7/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.7.0/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/base.rb:485:in `start'
    from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.7.7/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.7.0/bundler/cli.rb:28:in `start'
    from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.7.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.4.1/exe/bundle:45:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.7.7/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.7.0/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:117:in `with_friendly_errors'
    from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.7.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.4.1/exe/bundle:33:in `<top (required)>'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/.rbenv/versions/2.7.7/bin/bundle:25:in `load'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/.rbenv/versions/2.7.7/bin/bundle:25:in `<main>'
```

Initially there was a misconfiguration with our VPC such that there was no outbound internet access on one of our public and one of our private subnets. I corrected that and the error does not happen while connected to the public subnets but it does happen on the private subnets. I launched EC2 instances in the private subnets and verified they do have outbound internet access so it seems to be something related to my beanstalk instance.

I have verified our environment lines up with the template here https://github.com/awsdocs/elastic-beanstalk-samples/blob/master/cfn-templates/vpc-privatepublic.yaml but still no luck.

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue. I had enable HTTPS all the way to the instance by following steps here
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/https-tcp-passthrough.html
and here
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/https-singleinstance-ruby.html#Puma During that set up, it has you do this step
[image: AWS HTTPS SETUP]

The key being that this only needs done on the default VPC. Not sure why this didn't break things when I had everything on my public subnets but alas the problem is solved